# vim: E212: Can't open file for writing (even when using sudo)

Tags: 18.04, vim

I'm trying to write to /usr/share/application/whatever.desktop and every time I try to save, using vim, I get the following error:

> E212: Can't open file for writing

I get this error even using sudo.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such directory `/usr/share/application/`.

It is:

```
/usr/share/applications/
```

You are missing the final `s`.